# start app always from launcher activity

Tags: java, android

My app contains 3 activities . Let's say A,B,C . A is start up activity. Now run app this way - A -> B -> C Now i press Home key (home screen appears). Now when i again press app icon to start app , then start with activity C at front. But i want my app always start with activity A when press app icon on home screen.

How can i do it ?

I don't want to kill application onPause() or OnStop(), but only want to kill when home button is pressed. I've googled allot to CATCH HOME BUTTON but couldn't succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

When starting `Activities` B and C, use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` flag with the `Intent` to prevent these `Activities` from being saved on the stack. When you'll leave the application and start it again from the launcher, `Activity` A will be started. Here's the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try adding following tag with your launcher Activity on manifest file.

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```